# slow eclipse remote debugging connection

Tags: eclipse, linux-mint

I'm running linux mint 14, java 1.7.0_06-b24, eclipse 4.2.  I'm building and deploying a large web app to a local WebLogic instance.  When I try to connect a remote debugging session to this app for Eclipse debugging purposes, it takes quite a while ~1min to connect.  Once connected, performance seems fine.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Everything seemed to be working fine when I was running ubuntu and eclipse 3.8.

Comment: Things have gone from bad to worse.  My debugger no longer seems to be attaching at all.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set a big amount of breakpoints in your code?
Attaching to the JVM takes longer as more breakpoints are there.

Comment: I guess it depends on what constitutes a "big amount".  Maybe a few dozen or so would be my guess.

Comment: Well, i had like 30 maybe and I checked that CPU/RAM usage maxed at Tomcat machine while trying to connect during almost 2 minutes. I removed them all and now the connection is immediate.

Answer (score 1):

If the experimental debugging feature `Show debug values inline on text editors` is enabled, it takes ~1min to connect the remote debugger.

This was introduced in version 2022-03 (4.23.0).

Solution: disable the setting.
You can find it in `Window / Preferences / Run/Debug`